# Can gnuplot transparently open compressed data files to save storage space?

Tags: gzip, pipe, gnuplot, zlib

I have gigabytes of data that would be nice to compress with gzip for storage. Can gnuplot open compressed files? If it can't, is there a way to pipe the data to gnuplot so that the uncompressed file doesn't need to be written to disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like `plot "< gzip -dc compressed.gz"`, IIRC.

Comment: This worked. I did not know you could put shell commands inside gnuplot. Thanks!